# change a color to a header in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I want to change the font color in my header, so, I'm delegating the viewForHeaderInSection:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];

     UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];

    [headerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [headerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return headerView;
 }
```

The background color is set but the text likes to be transparent, there is nothing.

I tried to comment the backgroundColor the white disappears but the text doesnt.

I tried to comment all the block and the text appears with the default color.

where is my mistake? Thank you in advance

I found it, I missed:

```
[headerLabel setText: @"myText"];
```

It seems that:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
```

is not called when implementing viewForHeaderInSection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this method from the UITableViewDelegate protocol will get you started:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
 if (section == integerRepresentingYourSectionOfInterest)
 [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  else 
 [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  return headerView;
}
```

Replace [UIColor redColor] with whichever UIColor you would like. You may also wish to adjust the dimensions of headerView.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the font color, but I've already got it! I edited my post. Thanks!